# regex search and delete everything in brackets () using vim

Tags: regex, vim, pacman-package-manager

I have a file text like below:

```
java-environment-common (3-1)
jdk8-openjdk (8.u172-2)
libart-lgpl (2.3.21-4)
expect (5.45.4-1)
dejagnu (1.6.1-1)
cython2 (0.28.4-1)
python2-pytz (2018.5-1)
python2-sip (4.19.8-1)
```

And I want to remove all the text in bracket (bracket included).

I use `%s/\(.*\)//g`, but it remove each line.

Finally, I get the true answer: `%s/\s\(.*\)//g`! But why the result of the regex are so different, the second just remove a space.

Please tell me the reason, thanks!

Comment: In the non-very magic mode, `\(...\)` creates a capturing group. You must be looking for `%s/\s*(.*)//g`

Comment: \s?\(.*\) this would be standard format, but I can't help you accomodate it for VIM

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, your answer is correct. I'm confused about capturing group, cause `%s/\%(.*\)//g` removed each line, too. As I know the `capturing group` just save the text in bracket to `\1`. And what if my file text like(I removed the space): `java-environment-common(3-1)`.What should I do? ths.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove spaces before `(`? Or before the `(...)` substring at the end of the line? You may use `%s/\s*([^()]*)$//g` to remove~0+ whitespace and then a `(...)` substring at the end of the line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In the non-very magic mode, `\(...\)` creates a *capturing group*, you do not actually match literal `(` and `)` with `\(` and `\)`.

You must be looking for

```
%s/\s*(.*)//g
```

After running this command, I get the following output:

```
java-environment-common
jdk8-openjdk
libart-lgpl
expect
dejagnu
cython2
python2-pytz
python2-sip
```

To only remove 0+ whitespaces and the following `(...)` substring at the end of the line you may use

```
%s/\s*([^()]*)$//g
```

Where

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(` - a literal `(` (in a non-very magic mode)
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `)` - a literal `)` (in a non-very magic mode)
- `$` - end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You are accidentally creating capture groups by putting the escaping slash, `\` before your brackets. To vim, this means that whatever you find thanks to the regex we place inside these brackets should be saved so we can use those values again in our replace. It's actually not searching for the brackets at all! What you are actually doing in `%s/\s\(.*\)//g` is finding a whitespace with `\s` followed by **any number of any character**, saving these characters for later use and then replacing everything found with nothing (not using the values you saved earlier). This also just so happens to delete your brackets and their contents **but not for the reasons you think it is**.

If you wanted to search for the brackets, delete them and delete everything inside them, the right way would be to not escape your brackets, like this:

`:%s/\s(.*)$//g`
here I am telling vim to find a whitespace, followed by an opening bracket, followed by any number of any characters, followed by a closing bracket, followed by a newline (endline) character, then I tell it to replace everything with nothing (indicated by`//` )

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Another command

```
:%norm f(D

% ...... the whole file
f( ..... jump to the next (
D ...... erases till the end of line
```

Using `t(` instead of `f(` we can also delete the spaces

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

`:%s/\s(.*)//g`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `:normal command` (more info here : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_normal_command_in_a_script_for_searching)
in your specific case, you can use the following:
`:normal /(/di`

Explanation of the command: Look for a `(` then `di` will delete inside the scope of the ().